# Find string in a string and then some

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have a database which is storing the contents of a tinyMce editor as HTML.
When a user inserts a link to a file it creates the following HTML in the field stored in MySQL.

```
<p><a class="document_preview" title="Document.docx" href="documents/A123/Document.docx" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">&nbsp;Document.</a></p>
```

When a user deletes the file I need to remove the HTML from the field so there is no longer a link to it, something like this ....

- Find the title (Document.docx)
- Locate the first instance of `<p>` before the found title and the last instance of `<p>` after the found title
- Remove it all

I can use `strpos` to find the start position of the title but am stuck with the rest!

Anyone?

Comment: Your life will be a lot easier if you can use a library that parses the html, so that you can access the parts with confidence.

Comment: Also keep in mind that only using the document name will (possibly) give false positives, what if an (other) user uploads a document with the same name?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is what you show the complete database field, though? If every value describes one document and they all have the same markup structure, then you can indeed do it with a simple regex. So please clarify.

Comment: I agree with @DarkBee. If you can, try to store something unique about the file in the HTML if at all possible such as an ID, and put it into a custom `data-` HTML attribute unique to your system. Although I agree with alexis, too, that a true DOM parser is much safer, searching for a paragraph tag start and end with your custom attribute should be a safer search at least.

Comment: @alexis. No the complete field will contain a lot more HTML. For example at the moment during testing I have this  <p>Test</p>
<p><a class="document_preview" title="Thermal Imaging Interface Specification Document.docx" href="documents/A123/Document.docx" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">&nbsp;Document</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: I have had a look at DOM libraries but still cant get anything close to working... does anyone have an example of finding a string within a string and then getting the first and last specified character? Example: "string = '<p>Hello everyone how are you<p>.. search for the word "how" and return the position of first and last <p>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php as your tags suggest it, you could try something like

```
<?php

$title='Document.docx';
$html='<p><a class="document_preview" title="Document.docx" href="documents/A123/Document.docx" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">&nbsp;Document.</a></p>';

$html=preg_replace('#<p><a .+title="'.$title.'" .+>(.+)</a></p>#', '$1', $html);

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: Regular expressions for markup can cause a lot of problems - better use proper DOM libraries